# Firefox only uses OBS virtual camera

Tags: camera, mac, obs

I'm on macOS (10.14.6) and have OBS installed. I tried out the virtual cam a while ago using the native virtual cam functionality (not the plugin) and now whenever I need to use my camera in Firefox (88.0b5), it uses my virtual cam. This is the case whether OBS is open or not and whether my virtual cam is "started" or not. I can't get it to use my macbook's normal webcam or even tell that it exists.

There don't seem to be any preferences in OBS (26.1.2) about disabling the virtual camera. How can I disable that feature entirely or just get Firefox to use my normal webcam instead of the virtual cam?

Answer (score 1):

If you no longer need the virtual camera, you can uninstall the virtual camera plugin (whether it was installed as a separate plugin or as part of an OBS update) using the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/obs-mac-virtualcam.plugin
sudo rm -rf /Library/Application\ Support/obs-studio/plugins/obs-mac-virtualcam
```

Once that is done, make sure to close OBS and restart (quit and open) Firefox.